# Quartz Composer - passing value inside patch without wiring

Tags: networking, quartz-composer

After few years I have opened again quartz composer. I remember that there was a plugin in the library that I could send values within the patch without wiring.

For example if I have a macro and I want to send a value of a number from the macro to the root I used to use a plugin that I could link the value to send by name.

Do you know what this plugin is called in the library?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the 3d party plug-in from kineme.net called "spooky send".

Send anything into the object, then set the channel you want to send it on. You also had to have a "spooky receive" patch somewhere, with the same channel and you could wire that object from there.

Comment: Thanks this is the one. Unfortunatelly the plugin DataTool is not recognised anymore on osx Sierra thats why I could not find it. Any solution for sierrausers?

Comment: I am running Sierra and see it, and works. Are you sure you put it in the correct location. Mine is in /Users/ushername/Library/Graphics/Quartz Composer Patches

Comment: I have put it in the folder plugin

Comment: The Plug-In bundles seem to be a little more specific on where you have to put them. I would try putting it in the same location I have and restart QC.